# nested bool query does not match subset of product attributes

Tags: elasticsearch

For a number of days I am trying to index products in ES which apart from name, sku, id, price, attribue_set_name have got also subsets of atributes which mainly define available colour options or available product dimensions. More or less product structure looks like below:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 52
    [sku] => CHAI_0018
    [name] => Chair
    [name_lc] => chair
    [attr_set_name] => Chairs
    [price] => 34.00
    [attributes] => Array
        (
            [0] => 470
            [1] => 815
            [2] => 560
        )
    [super_attr] => Array
        (
            [0] => Olive
            [1] => Black
            [2] => Blue
            [3] => Clear
            [4] => Dark Grey
            [5] => Green
            [6] => Grey
            [7] => Light Blue
            [8] => Orange
            [9] => Purple
            [10] => Red
            [11] => White
            [12] => Yellow
        )
)
```

Considering that I don't have many products to index, instead products are configurable and I am only indexing parent products, I need to provide ability to search by one of the following fields:

- name_lc (lower case name)
- sku
- attr_set_name
- attributes (which I have also tried to implode to string)
- super_attr (also tried with imploding to string)

or combinations like "olive chairs", "olive chair" or "chair 470".

I create indexes with below mapping:

```
        $params = [
            'index' => $index,
            'body' => [
                'settings' => [
                    'analysis' => [
                        'analyzer' => [
                            'autocomplete' => [
                                'tokenizer' => 'autocomplete',
                                'filter' => [
                                    'lowercase'
                                ]
                            ],
                            'autocomplete_search' => [
                                'tokenizer' => 'lowercase'
                            ]
                        ],
                        'tokenizer' => [
                            'autocomplete' => [
                                'type' => 'edge_ngram',
                                'min_gram' => 1,
                                'max_gram' => 50,
                                'token_chars' => [
                                    'letter',
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                'mappings' => [
                    '_doc' => [
                        'properties' => [
                            'name_lc' => [
                                'type' => 'text',
                                'analyzer' => 'autocomplete',
                                'search_analyzer' => 'autocomplete_search'
                            ],
                            'sku' => [
                                'type' => 'text',
                                'analyzer' => 'autocomplete',
                                'search_analyzer' => 'autocomplete_search'
                            ],
                            'attr_set_name' => [
                                'type' => 'text',
                                'analyzer' => 'autocomplete',
                                'search_analyzer' => 'autocomplete_search'
                            ],
                            'attributes' => [
                                'type' => 'text',
                                'analyzer' => 'autocomplete',
                                'search_analyzer' => 'autocomplete_search'
                            ],
                            'super_attr' => [
                                'type' => 'text',
                                'analyzer' => 'autocomplete',
                                'search_analyzer' => 'autocomplete_search'
                            ],
                            'id' => [
                                'type' => 'integer'
                            ],
                            'price' => [
                                'type' => 'float'
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];
```

After studying ES docs and going through dozens of articles found on google my closest and most successful results are generated by below query:

```
        $params = [
            'index' => $index,
            'size' => $hits,
            'type' => '_doc',
            'body' => [
                "query" => [
                    "bool" => [
                        "must" => [
                            ["match" => [
                                "name_lc" => [
                                    "query" => $phrase,
                                    'operator' => 'or',
                                ]]],
                        ],
                        "should" => [
                            ["match" => [
                                "name_lc" => [
                                    "query" => $phrase,
                                    'fuzziness' => '1',
                                    'operator' => 'and',
//                                    "boost" => 15
                                ]]],
                            ["bool" => [
                                "should" => [
                                    ["match" => [
                                        "sku" => [
                                            "query" => $phrase,
                                            'operator' => 'or',
                                            "boost" => 5
                                        ]]
                                    ],
                                    ["match" => [
                                        "attr_set_name" => [
                                            "query" => $phrase,
                                            'fuzziness' => '1',
                                            'operator' => 'or',
                                            "boost" => 5
                                        ]]
                                    ],
                                    ["match" => [
                                        "super_attr" => [
                                            'query' => $phrase,
                                            'fuzziness' => '1',
                                            'operator' => 'or',
                                            "boost" => 5
                                        ]]
                                    ],
                                    ["match" => [
                                        "attributes" => [
                                            'query' => $phrase,
                                            'fuzziness' => '1',
                                            'operator' => 'or',
                                            "boost" => 5
                                        ]]
                                    ],
                                ]
                            ]]
                        ],
                        "filter" => [
                            "range" => [
                                "price" => [
                                    "gte" => 0,
                                    "lte" => 1000,
                                    "boost" => 2.0
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];
```

This query however doesn't return any results if I search for words:

- "Olive" (super_attr)
- "Chair**s**" (attr_set_name)
- "CHAI" (prefix for the SKU)

This behaviour makes me think that nested bool query is not working as expected. I have tried number or combinations with mapping, lowering case across searchable fields as well as input text but I am not getting anywhere. Not sure if the problem lies in incorrect mapping or the query itself. I am using ES 6.5 and I am not getting any syntax errors just lack of results. I am aware that search across so many fields may not be the fastest but having just under 500 products in the index I don't think this will product performance issues.

Oh and in regards to the price range filter, it is filtering correctly.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I wasn't too far from the what I wanted to achive.
For anyone who will get here, I am posting my solution to the problem.
In short, my mapping wasn't correct, as I used fields text for:

- id
- sku
- attr_set_name

after updating my mapping and setting field type to "keyword" things became even more promising. I decided to rework my query and search for exact matches in these fields using "term". Then in turned out that the exact matches have to be boosted slightly. After making more cosmetic changes, the final mapping looks as below:

```
        $params = [
            'index' => $index,
            'body' => [
                'settings' => [
                    'analysis' => [
                        'analyzer' => [
                            'autocomplete' => [
                                'tokenizer' => 'autocomplete',
                                'filter' => [
                                    'lowercase'
                                ]
                            ],
                            'autocomplete_search' => [
                                'tokenizer' => 'lowercase'
                            ]
                        ],
                        'tokenizer' => [
                            'autocomplete' => [
                                'type' => 'edge_ngram',
                                'min_gram' => 1,
                                'max_gram' => 50,
                                'token_chars' => [
                                    'letter',
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                'mappings' => [
                    '_doc' => [
                        'properties' => [
                            'id' => [
                                'type' => 'keyword'
                            ],
                            'sku' => [
                                'type' => 'keyword',
                            ],
                            'attr_set_name' => [
                                'type' => 'keyword',
                            ],
                            'name_search' => [
                                'type' => 'text',
                                'analyzer' => 'autocomplete',
                                'search_analyzer' => 'autocomplete_search'
                            ],
                            'attributes' => [
                                'type' => 'text',
                                'analyzer' => 'autocomplete',
                                'search_analyzer' => 'autocomplete_search'
                            ],
                            'super_attr' => [
                                'type' => 'text',
                                'analyzer' => 'autocomplete',
                                'search_analyzer' => 'autocomplete_search'
                            ],
                            'price' => [
                                'type' => 'float'
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];
```

and query which work well with this:

```
        $params = [
            'index' => $index,
            'size' => $hits,
            'type' => '_doc',
            'body' => [
                "query" => [
                    "bool" => [
                        'should' => [
                            ['match' => [
                                'name_search' => [
                                    'query' => $phrase,
                                    'operator' => 'and',
                                    'boost' => 4,
                                ]
                            ]],
                            ['match' => [
                                'name_search' => [
                                    'query' => $phrase,
                                    'operator' => 'or',
                                    'fuzziness' => '1',
                                    'boost' => 2,
                                ]
                            ]],
                            ['match' => ['attr_set_name' => $phrase]],
                            ['match' => [
                                'super_attr' => [
                                    'query' => $phrase,
                                    'boost' => 7,
                                ]
                            ]],
                            ['match' => ['attributes' => $phrase]],
                            ['term' => [
                                'sku' => [
                                'value' => $phrase,
                                "boost" => 5.0
                                ]
                            ]],
                            ['term' => [
                                'id' => [
                                    'value' => $phrase,
                                    "boost" => 5.0
                                ]
                            ]],
                        ],
                        "filter" => [
                            "range" => [
                                "price" => [
                                    "gte" => $min,
                                    "lte" => $max,
                                    "boost" => 2.0
                                ]
                            ]
                        ],
                        "minimum_should_match" => 2,
                    ],
                ]
            ]
        ];
```

I hope it will help someone one day :D